# Xamarin Forms (Portable) keeping the currently selected textbox in focus when keyboard pops up

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.windows

I am using a `ContentPage` in a Xamarin.Forms project in Visual Studio 2015 with C# where I have a few text input boxes postioned at the bottom of the screen. I want that the screen reposition itself to show in view the current textbox which has the cursor when the onscreen keypad pops up. When the user cancels the keypad the form should expand back into its original position before the keypad popped up. I am using [this link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scroll-view/) to figure this out, but it is not working. The keypad still covers the textbox. Here is the Xaml of the screen.

```
  <ContentPage>
      <ContentPage.Padding>
          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
              <OnPlatform.WinPhone>0, 20, 0, 0</OnPlatform.WinPhone>
          </OnPlatform>
      </ContentPage.Padding>   

    <ContentPage.Content>
      <ScrollView >

        <StackLayout >
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="162" WidthRequest="150" />
            <Entry Placeholder="Username" Text="{Binding UserName}"></Entry> 
            <Entry Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True" Text="{Binding Pass}"></Entry> 

            <Button Text="Login" Command="{Binding onClicked}" />

        </StackLayout>
      </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>

  </ContentPage>
```

Is there something that I might have missed in that article?

**EDIT**: Adding Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you post the image of your screen in which the problem is?@user20358

Comment: @AkashAmin updated with screenshot.

Comment: Did you try `WindowSoftInputMode =SoftInput.AdjustPan` in your activity? @user20358

Comment: No. I am using a xamarin portable project. I want this setting to apply to all the target platforms. There are no pages in the Android project.

Comment: I really did not understand the purpose of the ScrollView. It seems to do nothing.. as yet.

Comment: Yes I know that there are no pages in Android,  but if you keep that in the activity from where your forms application load it will be applied to all pages in the forms application.  Its a one time effort.

Comment: Would this work for other platforms in the solution too? This looks like it will only work for Android

Comment: Yes that was for android. I think your android and iOS would be working perfectly, the problem is in windows phone application. Many people have faced this issue of the Scroll View not scrolling. I found this on bugzilla https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=28577 . I'm not sure if you are using the latest version of Xamarin.Forms

Comment: This might help you. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21565/scrollview-inside-stacklayout-not-visible